# How to get proper event propagation with hammer.js 2?

Tags: javascript, touch, hammer.js, event-propagation

I'm using Hammer.js 2.0.4 in a situation where I have two hammerjs instances to listen for `tap` events: on in a parent div element, and one in a child. I would like to stop event propagation when handled by the child. However, hammer.js 2 does not support that.

In the following example, I would expect that the `tap` event of the child fires first, and then that of the parent (event bubbling from child to parent). Instead, it looks like the `tap` event of the *first created instance* of hammer.js fires first.

Try the following example ([also on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lokexi/edit?html,output)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/hammerjs/2.0.4/hammer.js"></script>
  <style>
    #child {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background: lightgreen;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
  See the browser console. Why does the tap event of the parent div fire first?
</p>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">click here</div>
</div>

<script>
  var hammerParent = new Hammer(document.getElementById('parent'));
  var hammerChild = new Hammer(document.getElementById('child'));

  hammerParent.on('tap', function (event) {
    console.log('tap parent');
  });

  hammerChild.on('tap', function (event) {
    console.log('tap child');
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas how to get a proper event propagation working in hammer.js?

Answer (score 3):

I created a little library on top of hammer.js v2 to resolve the propagating issue:

https://github.com/josdejong/propagating-hammerjs

Still, it would be great if hammer.js would support this right out of the box.